# explain this code of list comprehensions with lamba inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def mul():
    return [lambda x : i*x for i in range(4)]
```

when i execute it i get this

```
[<function __main__.mul.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
<function __main__.mul.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
<function __main__.mul.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
<function __main__.mul.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda>>]
```

and i am using that function as like this

```
print([f(3) for f in mul()])
[9, 9, 9, 9]

print([f(5) for f in mul()])
[15, 15, 15, 15]
```

what is happening inside of mul() and inside of print and what here f refers to?

Comment: `i` is a closure; it doesn't store the value of `i` when you create the `lambda`, it stores a reference to the same variable, and this variable last referenced `3`.

Comment: @Jérôme: this isn't limited to lambdas, see [Local variables in Python nested functions](//stackoverflow.com/q/12423614)